# VBA in MS Access Syntax error on Dim

Tags: ms-access, vba, syntax-error

I'm updating an app written by someone else in MS Access 2013 and I keep getting a syntax error on one of my Dim statements. I've been searching the internet for 45 minutes and can't figure out what is wrong. Here is a code snippet:

```
Sub refreshData()
   Dim strSQL as string
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim db As Database
'Rest of sub
```

When I run the app, VBA highlights the "Sub" line in yellow, the "Dim strSQL" line in blue and pops a dialog that says "Syntax Error". If I try to remove "as string" it does the same thing. I come from a background of Java and PHP programming, so I am unfamiliar with VBA. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What's above `Sub`? Maybe Sub is in an invalid context? `Sub` can only be used at the module level (class, structure, module, or interface). Also, try removing the entire content of the procedure (between `Sub` & `End Sub` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Try using Private Sub refreshData().  I am wondering why the "as string" are not capitalized.  The IDE should auto capitalize them...

Comment: All of the code above "Sub refreshData()":
 `Option Compare Database


Private Sub Form_Load()
    refreshData
    
End Sub`
Changing it to "Private Sub" makes no difference. I also tried changing it to "Function" instead of "Sub", it gives the same error. Edit: comment box ignores new lines, creating an answer for this instead so it is more clear.